# Serialization protocol options in Python Shelve

Tags: python, serialization, shelve

Which are the protocols I can use in the shelve module of Python besides Pickle? What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deciding by http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html, `shelve` only works with pickle; the protocol parameter simply seems to specify the pickle version.